# How to run gui application on windows vm?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows, vagrant-plugin

I have installed vagrant and virtual box on my Mac. I have created a Windows10 VM and it's configured with winrm.

I am able to run commands on Windows VM through vagrant. However I am not able to see any GUI on the VM.

For example, if I open command prompt in Windows VM and issue command "start chrome.exe", it launches the chrome browser and browser ui is displayed. However if I type the same command through winrm `vagrant winrm -c "start chrome.exe"`, it launches the browser, but ui is not displayed in VM.Same issue happens if I run commands through shell provisioner.

Is there any way, I can run commands from vagrant and the application will be launched in GUI mode in VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way, I can run commands from vagrant and the application will be launched in GUI mode in VM?

No.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426(v=vs.85).aspx :

> You can use WinRM scripting objects, the WinRM command-line tool, or the Windows Remote Shell command line tool WinRS to obtain management data from local and remote computers ...

winrm is used for **Remote Management** and does not forward the X window, so no you cannot launch a program like chrome and forward the UI somewhere else.

Your best options to run UI program from your VM :

- run from the VM GUI (either by enabling from Vagrantfile or opening the VM from VirtualBox)
- running [vagrant rdp](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rdp.html) to login into the VM

Comment: You can add a link to your app on the Window's start up, then it will be ran on vm startup.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to run the VM in 'GUI mode' (as opposed to 'headless').
I use VirtualBox from Oracle, which is one of the options easily configured from within your Vagrantfile.

Check out my "Provider-specific configuration" section:

```
  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #        # (so we can run the browser)
     vb.gui = true
     vb.name = "windows10-eval"
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
     vb.memory = "2048"
   end
```

When my VM boots I automatically get a GUI which looks exactly as if I was booting a regular Windows machine.  This box comes conveniently with chrome already provisioned, but it'd be easy to install it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't directly run a GUI app from the WinRM, you can also add a link to your app in the Windows startup so you will ensure the app is ran on system startup.

Add the following in your provisioning script :

```
mklink C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\"Start Menu"\Programs\Startup\MyApp.link C:\MyApp\\MyApp.exe
shutdown /r /t 1
```